# Reference, pointer or value semantics in C/C++ functions

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have simple code to trim the string

```
std::string TrimEnd(const std::string& str, const std::string& chars)
{
    std::string trimmed = str;
    int index = 0;
    if((index = trimmed.find_last_not_of(chars)) < trimmed.length() - 1)
            trimmed.erase(index + 1);
    return trimmed;
}
```

I use references for arguments and value for function return. Is there any preference to use pointers instead? In my case a copy of the trimmed string is returned. In some functions const reference is returned.

Comment: If you are just going to copy `str`, why are you passing as reference in the first place? Just pass it by-value.

Comment: it is a good style to not to change function arguments

Comment: Maybe in a situation where you are developing a highly used C++ library, yes. But for an in-house application, you can safely pass arguments however you want. Better to be clear with what's happening when you pass an arg to a function, than to have people think that you're passing a `const` reference (meaning it will only be read from).

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy no, it is perfectly OK to modify function arguments, and your code has the chance to be more efficient if you make a copy by taking a parameter by value instead of making one yourself.

Comment: Please do not use the tag “C” for questions that do not make sense as C questions. Say, questions with lots of `std::string&` bits, whatever that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not in a general sense.  If you need to be able to pass in a NULL-ified pointer, or need to do some pointer arithmetic on the parameter, pass a pointer.  Otherwise, pass references by default.

Answer (score 2):

For C++ style, you return by value. pass by reference/const reference. ( value for POD )  *never* return by reference unless it refers to static storage, or to a member variable if you want to expose access to them ( typically const & would be used for that).. yes the return by value generates yet another copy, however  the older c++ standard allows compilers to optimize that out. And the new c++ 11 standard allows move constructors which are even more awesome.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to pass by reference if you return a new string, and you certainly don't want to return a reference to `trimmed` because it's scope is the `TrimEnd` method.

Unless you're trying to optimize your code I would pass by value. If you're writing your own string class (or something like that) and performance is your top priority, then I would do everything by reference.

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy Then I personally, would do it all by reference. Pass references, modify in place, return references. Memory management can become a problem however, if you for example want to make a concat method where the buffer is allocated in method (the programmer calling the method has to be responsible for freeing the memory).

Answer (score 0):

Here, since you’re making a copy of the first argument anyway, you may as well pass it by value:

```
std::string TrimEnd(std::string str, const std::string& chars)
{
    int index = 0;
    if((index = str.find_last_not_of(chars)) < str.length() - 1)
        str.erase(index + 1);
    return str;
}
```

In general:

- Pass object types by `const` reference.
- Pass primitives (e.g., `int`) by value, as well as object types when you need a mutable copy.
- Pass parameters by pointer when that pointer may be null.
- Return by value or smart pointer (e.g., `unique_ptr`); raw pointers have unclear ownership.

Comment: generally it is not a good style to change function arguments

Comment: @ChesnokovYuriy: True, but in this case I felt the explicit copy was unnecessary. It’s just a matter of preference. Most STL algorithms, for example, take iterator parameters by value and mutate them locally. Also, this style works if the type is movable and noncopyable; the original would need an explicit `std::move` and to pass by rvalue reference.

Comment: still I'm not comfortable by changing original function parameters